# Как заставить кэшировать Bundle в ASP .NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, кэширование, bundles

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Использую бандлы для минификации, но не получается их закэшировать.
Пробовал устанавливать Headers вручную, но они сбрасываются. 
Ни Pragma, ни Cache-Control не устанавливается.

Каким образом правильно настроить кэширование бандлов?

Comment: может использовать appcache у html'а https://www.html5rocks.com/ru/tutorials/appcache/beginner/

Answer (score 0):

Возможно вы отключили кэширование на уровне вер сервера для статики. Какой вы используете, на iis express развернули? Проверите настройки в 
web.config -> configuration -> web.server -> staticContent -> clientCache

Так же можно развернуть на iis и проверить там. Только включите кеширование статики

Comment: Iis 7. В web.config указана такая инструкция

Comment: <staticContent>
   <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseExpires" Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 GMT" />
</staticContent>

Comment: Отдельные скрипты(<scripts>...</scripts>) кэшируются, бандлы нет